# What does "http://:0" mean and how can I using C# to send HTTP request

Tags: c#

I'm using Wireshark to capture the HTTP data and want to use C# for simulation. But I don't know what `http://:0` means.

[image: Wireshark Follow TCP Stream]

Comment: You should have a look at Progress/Telerik Fiddler. It's a bit friendlier than Wireshark for interception of http calls, and there's an extension that will allow you to click on a particular request and generate the C# (or other) code necessary to recreate the request.

Comment: http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code

Comment: I think you have 2 problems and should split them up into seperate questions here. One is about understanding the `http://:0` and one about generating network traffic using C#

Comment: Hi  rory_za, thanks for your answer. But Fiddler can not capture my desktop application, my desktop application was built with visual c++.

Comment: Hi Murmel, thanks for you answer, But what does "http://:0" mean?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to read [Can I ask only one question per post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735)